# Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let'

Tags: javascript, filter, let

[image]

I am trying filter the object and when I do it I am getting this error what actually it is saying I am not getting it.

> Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let'.

This is my filter function

```
var arr = $scope.items; //object data
var stringToFilter = newSortingOrder.toString();
let obj = arr.find(o => o.id === stringToFilter); //error stopping in this line.
```

Comment: The `let` keyword requires a fairly up-to-date JavaScript environment.

Comment: What browser are you running this on? You could just use var instead of let in line 3

Comment: ES2015 isn't exactly a new thing - it's been supported by modern browsers for quite a while ago. Maybe OP is using IE

Comment: are you using jslint

Comment: if it doesn't like `let` then it definitely won't like `find(o => o.id === stringToFilter)`

Comment: It would help if you bothered to say what environment this is.. code editor, browser/version, linter etc

Comment: @Mrworldwide use ES5 syntax `var obj = arr.find(function(o) { return o.id === stringToFilter; });`

Comment: Try replacing `let` with `var` as suggested in the first comment.

Comment: That "Service Now" thing looks like it's providing a JavaScript environment based on a Java environment, so it could be some old version of Rhino.

Comment: @igor it's just the line above but clipped by the image newSortingOrder.toString // clipped here

Comment: If you've written all your code in ES6 but need ES5 support you could use babel. See: http://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: The message looks like a lint error. There are two ways to handle lint errors, eiher configure the linter so that it supports your JS version, or write the code according to the requirements set in the lint configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let obj = arr.find(o => o.id === stringToFilter);
```

Is ES2015/ES6 (they're the same) syntax and, although it's not exactly new, not all environments will support it.

Use ES5 syntax instead to resolve your issue. It's much more widely supported.

```
var obj = arr.find(function(o) { return o.id === stringToFilter; });
```